# Undertow on springboot ignores server.ssl.ciphers property

Tags: ssl, spring-boot, undertow

I'm running SpringBoot 1.3.1 with undertow. I have an SSL connection but I would like to configure the set of allowed ciphers using the server.ssl.ciphers property, however undertow ignores these configurations and uses the same cipher even if it is not in the configured list.

Any hints?

Thank You,
Rui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for configuring Undertow via `server.ssl.ciphers` was [added in Spring Boot 1.4](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/4823), so your easiest option may be to upgrade. 1.3.x (and 1.4.x) are no longer supported so upgrading is recommended anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much. Upgrading wasn't exactly an option so I debug the code and found out that Jetty and Tomcat were using the "ssl.class#getCiphers()" so I ended up switching the engine from undertow to tomcat and worked. Thanks for your answer :)